# How do extract data between two terms in a string?

Tags: c#

```
<a href="https://genius.com/Run-the-jewels-lie-cheat-steal-lyrics" class=" song_link" title="Lie, Cheat, Steal by&nbsp;Run&nbsp;the Jewels">
```

I'm trying to extract the link that's in between href="", and set it to a string. Is there any way to do that?
The data in it will change consistantly, it's not always gonna be the same domain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and easy: find the text between `href="` and the next `"` (as `"` will never appear in the value):

```
Int32 startIdx = input.IndexOf( "href=\"" );
if( startIdx < 0 ) return null;
Int32 endIdx = input.IndexOf( "\"", startIdx );
if( endIdx < 0 ) return null;
return input.Substring( startIdx, endIdx - startIdx );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can find this elsewhere on Stack, but I would use string.split(). You can set up something similar to this...

```
public static void Main(){

     char[] delimiterChars = { '"', ' ' };

     string text = "<a href=\"https://genius.com/Run-the-jewels-lie-cheat-steal-lyrics\" class=\" song_link\" title=\"Lie, Cheat, Steal by&nbsp;Run&nbsp;the Jewels\">";

      string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
}
```

Assuming your tag is always structured the same, you will just need to grab the third string in the array to pull out the value you are looking for. You can also search for the index of href, and then split the string based on that, but this is how I would go about it.